# Why does a line with invalid type annotation behave differently inside and outside a function?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

This Python program errors, somewhat expectedly (I messed up `list(int)` and `list[int]`):

```py
var: list(int) = []
print(var)
```

In line with this, `mypy` reports

```
bug.py:2: error: Invalid type comment or annotation
bug.py:2: note: Suggestion: use list[...] instead of list(...)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, the following code runs fine, and `mypy` does not report anything:

```py
def fun():
    var: list(int) = []
    print(var)

fun()
```

Why?

Comment: The type hint within the function seems to be ignored in your environment and also in mine (Visual Studio Code with IntelliSense (Pylance)). The difference with IntelliSense is that the first code fragment produces *TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable*

Comment: The `mypy` part of the issue is explained in https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code. TLDR: `mypy` ignores functions without annotations.

Comment: Interesting. I defined a function with valid type hints for both its input parameters and return value. I then added an invalid type hint *var: list(int) = []* within the function and IntelliSense did not report any error. So there's obviously inconsistency between the various linters